# Should a custom event have get methods?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, methods, coding-style

I created some custom events in a desktop application and gave it some get methods in order to grab the data that is associated with the event. It seems odd to be calling 'get' methods on an event. Is this bad programming practice, should I make the event properties public instead?

Here is my custom event...

```
package classes.events
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class ListItemClickedEvent extends Event
{
    public static var PROJECT_CHOSEN:String = "project_chosen";
    private var projectName:String;
    private var projectLabel:String;
    private var projectFolder:String;

    public function ListItemClickedEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = true, 
                                    cancelable:Boolean = false, pName:String = null, 
                                    pLabel:String = null, pFolder:String = null){
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        projectName = pName;
        projectLabel = pLabel;
        projectFolder = pFolder;
    }

    override public function clone():Event{
        return new ListItemClickedEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    public function getProjectName():String{
        return projectName;
    }
    public function getProjectLabel():String{
        return projectLabel;
    }
    public function getProjectFolder():String{
        return projectFolder;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Yeah usually there are just public properties. You should pass your custom properties in the clone function though, otherwise they will go missing if you would catch up the event somewhere and then dispatch it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex events like [ListEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ListEvent.html) or [MenuEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/MenuEvent.html) simply use public variables, but feel free to use any access practice you like: getter functions, properties or public variables. It's your class and you can use your own style.